What is the difference between nvme0n1 and nvme1n1?
Some systems have a drive called nvme0n1 and others have a drive called nvme1n1, or a system will have both drives, but with different storage amounts. Why? What is the difference between these, and what does it mean that they are named differently?
Example from computer 1:
lsblk -dno NAME,SIZE,TYPE | grep nvme
nvme1n1     8G disk
nvme0n1 139.7G disk

Example from computer 2:
lsblk -dno NAME,SIZE,TYPE | grep nvme
nvme1n1 139.7G disk
nvme0n1     8G disk

A similar (but distinct) question was asked here, with no answers:
why nvme device name is nvme1c1n1, not nvme0n1?

You have two nvme's and their order is not fixed. Whichever was detected first today is the one that grabbed nvme0 and the other got nvme1.

Two different drives like sda & sdb. But small NVMe drive often was a Microsoft requirement for a Windows boot cache, just to speed booting as Windows boots so slow. May be Intel Optane or Intel RST settings in UEFI. Often Optane causes issues, so users uninstall it and put in a much larger NVMe drive.

@frostschutz interesting, thanks. AWS inconsistently assigns one but not the other of these NVMe drives to have storage space
